# Firebase: Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to authenticate the identity of users for my firebase app.
For this, I' doing custom authentication. 
Which generates a `User_Id` key.

However, after generating the `token` using this `User_Id` key. 
When I use that token inside `signInWithCustomToken` function, it says. 
"The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation."
with permission denied error.

Database rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

​

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');

var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");

//firebase configuration
var config = {
    apiKey: "<APP-secret-key>",
    authDomain: "<auth-domain>",
    databaseURL: "<database-url>",
    storageBucket: "",
};

//initialize your firebase app
var fireApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

//connect to database
var database = firebase.database();

var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("<APP-secret-key>");
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken({ uid: "User_id"});
  //get reference for 'user' document
 fireApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log('firebaseerrors', errorMessage);
  // ...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the top of the README of the [token generator project on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-node):

> **WARNING: This token generator is compatible with versions 1.x.x and 2.x.x of the Firebase SDK. If you are using the 3.x.x SDK, please refer to the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#create_a_custom_token).**